# Upload file via selenium if 3rd party api service is using to upload file

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload

Here is page im trying to upload file with selenium/python

`<div class="form-group-inner photo-form-group-inner success icn-item"><span class="label">Photo ID</span><div class="photo-label-wrapper"><div class="photo-label btn_fix-width"><label for="photo" class="btn btn_fix-width btn_block border photo-btn">Upload</label></div></div><input type="file" id="photo" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"></div>`

I tried it via *sendkeys*
Tried to change *file type* to **text** and apply path as well.
In additional upload uses 3rd party service via api request to store images.
While writing this post figured out that could try to send api request to get uploaded file code but how to put it to the page field css item in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the Selenium route, you could try to execute some Javascript on the file input to reveal it, then send keys to it:

```
# fetch the input
file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")

# reveal the input with JS
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", file_input)

# send keys
file_input.send_keys(path_to_file)
```

I have used this solution many times in the past with success.

Comment: Thanks, tried it in this way, but didn't help: `execute_java_script("document.getElementById('photo').value='/Users/user/Downloads/image.png'")`  In additional tried changing type: `execute_java_script("document.getElementById('photo').setAttribute('type', 'text');")` Will try your way.

Comment: `execute_java_script()` isn't a valid method on `driver` -- the correct syntax is `driver.execute_script()`. So that may have been why it wasn't working.